# Backbone.js Collection URL - 404 Not Found

Tags: backbone.js, collections

I'm following the beginner Backbone.js tutorial video by Thomas Davis on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk)

I run into an issue recreating his first collection, the users collection.

```
var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url: '/users'
        });
```

I have a div with a class of "page in the html markup, of which the html should contain "Test Content" on success of fetching an instance of Users:

```
var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '.page',
            render: function () {
                var users = new Users();
                users.fetch({
                    success: function () {
                        this.$el.html('Test Content');
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

I'm working in the "backbone" directory on a server (eg: work.mysite.local/backbone)

I'm having trouble understanding what my collection URL should resolve to,

Both "work.mysite.local/users" and "work.mysite.local/backbone/users" give me 404 errors.

The author of the video uses an ajax Prefilter, which prepends the name of his remote server to the url of the collection, which I'm not sure if I need to use or not.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the server code is written in node.js nd it here:
https://github.com/thomasdavis/video-backbone-beginner-server

The client code is in this repository:
https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/tree/gh-pages/videos/beginner